# Five-minute limit on editing comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Does the five-minute limit on editing comments really accomplish anything?

If I realize that I have made a significant error (for example, my iPad has an extremely bad habit of inexplicably relocating my insertion point while I am typing), but I don't see it within five minutes, I just copy, delete, and paste into a new comment.  I have done that at least four times, probably more.

The only way to stop me is to prevent deleting comments.  And there are many situations where that would be a bad idea.

Comment: The comment edit limit is to prevent you from posting one thing and then changing it into something else when other people reply to your comment.

Comment: That's a good reason, but as I said, the limit doesn't really work if deletions are allowed, and they must be allowed.

Comment: I must admit I also do find the time limit strange. Comments are often only temporarily, can deleted at will (from both author and moderators) and if they are moved to chat, in most cases they are dying lonely and forgotten. If someone would continously abuse the feature, we would be aware of it and put a thumb on it? Are there cases where someone changes his comments abusively?

Comment: I suppose part of the problem is that there is no history for comment edits. Questions and answers can be edited anytime, but there's a history log, so everyone can see what changed and react accordingly. Comment edits are invisible, so abuse is hard to notice. Deleting and re-commenting isn't really such a bad thing if it's necessary.

Comment: But delete and replace is effectively editing, so the restriction is an illusion.

Comment: Not entirely so; delete and repost changes the sequencing.  It is then clear that earlier responses are responding to something now missing, instead of appearing to be *non sequiturs* of some earlier statement that no longer makes a particular point.

Comment: Point taken.  In that case I would suggest instead of a time limit, a check whether another comment has been made since.  Because it's also possible to comment, see a response, and then edit before five minutes expires.